# How connect spring boot app to DigitalOcean managed DB

Tags: mysql, linux, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have Spring boot app which I deploy on droplet in digitalocean. For mysql I create Managed Mysql DB on Digital ocean. After setup digitalocean give me information for connection like:

String:

```
mysql://doadmin:show-password@mysqlb1-do-user-8042482-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060/defaultdb?ssl-mode=REQUIRED
```

For connection to local mysql I use this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test8?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

I can't connect it throw exception:

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, mysql://doadmin:show-password@mysqlb1-do-user-8042482-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060/defaultdb?ssl-mode=REQUIRED
```

I added my Ip to Trusted sources.
How connect to db properly?

EDIT:

I managed to connect with MySqlWorkbench but couldn't with app on tomcat and spring boot/intelij.

EDIT 2:
It look like connection established with this:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysqlb1-do-user-8042482-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060/defaultdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&requireSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= doadmin
spring.datasource.password= password
```

but throw error :

```
2020-09-20 14:18:57.531  WARN 10640 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2020-09-20 14:18:57.532 ERROR 10640 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'defaultdb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to connect DB from your computer, please always connect from your VPS, but if you decide to do that, please follow the next guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need test app before deploy on server. So I try connect spring boot app with thisd managed db but couldn't connect when MySql Workbench  connect after 5 try :)